# How do I store this type of class relationship in database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, class

Say I have the following Classes:

- EmailAddress
- Address
- Contact
- User
- Event
- Task
- Note

Each Contact can have multiple EmailAddresses or multiple Addresses, and Users can also have multiple of each. (Home Address, Business Address or Personal Email, Business Email, etc)

I was thinking that maybe I should make the User class extend the Contact class. That would mean that I would have a field in the EmailAddress and Address classes that references the Contact they belong to.

Then I would want to be able to attach a note to any of the following types: Event, Task or Contact. I would also want to be able to attach multiple notes to those types. I can't think of a good way to design this structure in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried drawing your class model with the [Entity Data Model Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716685.aspx) and see what database model does it generate?

Comment: After you do it, you could post your diagram here and share the things you do not like, that will make this question a lot easier to answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if contact has the same properties as a user or if a contact is shared by users.  Let's take a simple case of contact not shared by users.  If email and phone is more complex than string then substitute in classes email and phone.

```
Class User 
   public String name 
   public List<string> emails 
   public List<string> phones
   public List<contact> contacts

Class Contact
   public String name 
   public List<string> emails
```

If contact has the exact same properties as User then

```
Class User 
   public String name 
   public List<string> emails 
   public List<string> phones
   public List<User> contacts
```

If you want to inherit then

```
   Class User : Contact 
       public List<string> phones
       public List<contact> contacts
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I have in code, the problem I have is how do I store the emails and phones in the database, and then how to determine if each is related to a User or a Contact.

Comment: Two ways to go about it.  Though maybe not 3rd normal form I would just have one table with PK iden and a boolean of User or Contact.  If user has more columns then contact you just have some blank.  Then just have a FK relationship to emails and it really does not care if it is User or Contact.  Of have one table for User and one for contact each with iden PK.  Then you have FK table userEmail and FK table contactEmail.

Comment: At the DB level there is not really a way for one table to inherit (extend) from another so the db design is basically independent from if the class inherits.